# Is there a lower level interface than handlers? I want more control over memory allocation

Tags: netty

AFAICT netty returns a new buffer on every read. At least by the time channelRead() in the handler gets called every msg has a different memory address.

I understand why. unless the user can guarantee the memory won't be accessed outside of that function. But seems slow and wasteful (even if the buffers are pooled and reference counted) if you don't have to do it.

I'd rather read/write to/from memory my app controls rather than netty controls. I understand the lifecycle of my memory usage. Netty doesn't.

Is there a lower-level interface into the eventloop? one where I can read into a buffer of my own choosing? (like every network api written in the last 50 years)?

or am I SOL here? I understand mine isn't the typical use case.. but still. it's supposed to be a high-performant networking library. I should have better control over memory than this.

Hopefully this exists and it's just not as documented as the normal use case.

Comment: I'd be surprised if so. There's only so much memory control a Java platform is going to expose. The "other low level network API from the last 50 years" aren't in memory managed environments.

Comment: @bishop I think you misunderstand. I just want to pass a buffer (in any form) to read/write just like the NIO & OIO libraries that come w/ java. that what I mean by ".. API from the last 50 years". I want to tell the network were to copy the bits too. that's it. netty is the only networking API I've seen that it seems hard to do that. Netty hands me a buffer w/ the bits already in it when it calls channelRead().

Comment: Indeed, I did misunderstand how low-level you meant. @Norman_Maurer is on the right track, IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to write your own `RecvByteBufAllocator` and / or `ByteBufAllocator`.

Comment: ByteBufAllocator looks very promising! Thank you. Now I just need to figure out how to attach one to a channel. (bootstrap doesn't seem to support). I'll report back.

Comment: So adding your own ByteBufAllocator to your channel will allow you to control which ByteBuf you read into.
But havaing messed with it for while, I can't help feeling like I really fighting the framework rather than working with it. I think if you need this level of control you should just write you own NIO impl. Netty is for for you.